# c# generic versus non generic enumerators

Tags: c#, generics, enumerable

A newbie question.

Arrays in C# return a non generic (classic) IEnumerator. Other collections can supply either.

In general, is it bettter use a generic enumerator if it is available, eg for reasons of type safety? Are there times when the non-generic option is preferable?

Comment: Remember that arrays were in C# 1 while generics didn't appear until C# 2, so it would have been tricky for arrays (and `ArrayList`, `HashTable` etc) to return them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Usually* it's highly preferable to use generic enumerations, for, as you mentioned in question, type safety.

Non generic enumeration *can* be a choice in case when you store just a collection of objects.
So instead of writing `IEnumerable<object>`, you write `IEnumerable` and figure out the *real* object type inside the iteration (if you need that, but usually yes).

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` doesn't actually always use the `IEnumerable[<T>]` / `IEnumerator[<T>]` API *at all*. Firstly, it isn't actually required: all that is *required* is a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns *something* with a `bool MoveNext()` and `Current {get;}` - for example, `List<T>` has a custom iterator. This approach was also common in .NET 1.1 to avoid boxing, by giving preference to the custom iterator.

However, in the case of arrays it is perhaps even more interesting; consider:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach(var i in GetData()) Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    static int[] GetData()
    {
        int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        return data;
    }
```

Here, `Main` is compiled to (`//` comments are mine):

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 i,
        [1] int32[] CS$6$0000,
        [2] int32 CS$7$0001)

    // int[] arr = GetData()
    L_0000: call int32[] ConsoleApplication7.Program::GetData()
    L_0005: stloc.1

    // int j = 0
    L_0006: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0007: stloc.2

    // run end-condition of for loop first...
    L_0008: br.s L_0018

    // i = arr[j]
    L_000a: ldloc.1 
    L_000b: ldloc.2 
    L_000c: ldelem.i4          
    L_000d: stloc.0

    // Console.WriteLine(i);
    L_000e: ldloc.0 
    L_000f: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

    // j++
    L_0014: ldloc.2 
    L_0015: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0016: add 
    L_0017: stloc.2

    // j < arr.Length
    L_0018: ldloc.2 
    L_0019: ldloc.1 
    L_001a: ldlen 
    L_001b: conv.i4
    L_001c: blt.s L_000a

    L_001e: ret 
}
```

which makes *no use whatsoever* of the enumerator API; it has actually implemented it as a `for` loop.